# Space in path for docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker-compose

I am getting;

```
Error: Command failed: docker stack deploy --compose-file /Users/myUser/OneDrive - My Company/Code/myProject/node_modules/tools/lib/wdio/docker-compose.yml wdio
"docker stack deploy" requires exactly 1 argument.
```

I suspect the space in the path because the code is hosted on an MS OneDrive. I cannot change the name of the One Drive. Is there a way to get docker to handle the spaces correctly on a Mac/Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
docker stack deploy --compose-file /Users/myUser/OneDrive\ -\ My\ Company/Code/myProject/node_modules/tools/lib/wdio/docker-compose.yml wdio
```